VHDL - Multiple RAMs driving same Output
i'm having trouble getting my VHDL project working.
So far i have instanciated multiple RAM components with individual data outputs.
COMPONENT RAM 
PORT    (
                Clk                             :   IN      STD_LOGIC;
                En                              :   IN      STD_LOGIC;
                ReadNWrite                      :   IN      STD_LOGIC;
                Addr                            :   IN      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 8  DOWNTO 0 );
                RegIn                           :   IN      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7  DOWNTO 0 );
                RegOut                          :   OUT     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7  DOWNTO 0 )
            );
END COMPONENT;

If the En-Flag is '0' the RegOut is set to 0s.
As the RAMs have individual enable lines and i got a "linear adressing scheme" working, only one RAM drives its RegOut with actual data at a time - all the others drive it with 0s.
I instanciate multiple RAM modules in a Generate statement within the TOP module:
This works like a charme.... However, i'm having trouble to combine the Out_i "into a single" output DOut of the top module.
ENTITY TOP IS
    PORT (
                .....;
                DOut : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( ... DOWNTO 0 );
                .....
            );
END TOP;

ARCHITECTURE B OF TOP IS
   SIGNAL s_ChipSelect_H : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( ... DOWNTO 0 );
BEGIN

GEN_RAM : FOR i IN 0 TO ... GENERATE
    SIGNAL Out_i : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (... DOWNTO 0 );
BEGIN
        ram_i : RAM PORT MAP (
                            Clk,
                            s_ChipSelect_H(i),
                            RnW,
                            Adr,
                            InData,
                            Out_i
                        );
END GENERATE;
END B;

So the question is: How would i combine the generated Out_is "into a single" output DOut of the top module.

If you are sure, that at the time you read the data from Dout, no RAM or  only the RAM , you have read from, has its En-input at 1, then you can "or" all the outputs Out_i. If you are not sure you must use a multiplexer which selects the correct Out_i in the clock cycle when the data shows at Out_i.

@MatthiasSchweikart Thank you. How would i code the OR approach in a generic manner? Can i have a signal 'x' in the top and then do x <= x or x_i in the generate?

Please be aware of the following: You cannot in VHDL have a component output a vlue and have another value and feed it directly into the same signal. The compiler wiill complain for sure. I'm not even sure you can output 'Z' in component and '1' in the other component.  Always use a mux

You can do it in this way:
architecture B of TOP is 
    type array_of_std_logic_vector is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(... downto 0);
    signal or_array    : array_of_std_logic_vector(0 to number_of_rams);
    signal Out_i_array : array_of_std_logic_vector(0 to number_of_rams-1);
    ...
begin
    or_array(0) <= (others => '0');
    GEN_RAM : FOR i IN 0 TO number_of_rams-1 GENERATE
    BEGIN
        ram_i : RAM PORT MAP (
                    Clk,
                    s_ChipSelect_H(i),
                    RnW,
                    Adr,
                    InData,
                    Out_i_array(i)
                );
        or_array(i+1) <= or_array(i) or Out_i_array(i);
    END GENERATE;
END B;

Have a look at hdl_schem_editor, there you will find several examples for the use of GENERATE.

The hdl_schem_editor looks interesting.; seems similar to HDL Designer.

@Mikef: I was using HDL-Designer for 30 years and I admit, my work on HDL-SCHEM-Editor was influenced by this.
